# Find if a touch is inside a view in Android

Tags: android

I have an image and a `TextView` below the image which is the title for the image. When I touch the text i want to change the state of the image to selected. I capture the touch up and touch down events to change the state of image to selected and unselected respectively.

I want to implement touch cancel i.e. if I touch inside the `TextView` and drag outside and remove my finger the image state should be set to unselected. How do I know if a touch lies within a view?

My application target level is 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my Question. I solved this by placing the image view and text view inside a view. And setting the property duplicateParentState to true for the image view.

Answer (score 2):

you can do by flag variable like when you down flag on if you drag finger then off that flag like wise here

```
boolean isDown = false;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
    final int action=event.getAction();
    final int x=(int)event.getX();
    final int y=(int)event.getY();

    if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       isDown = true;
    }else if(acttion == Motion.ACTION_MOVE){
       isDown = false;
    }else if(action === MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if(isDown){
             // do something here
        }
    }
    return (isDown | super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is how do i know i Motion.Action_Move has moved out of the view or still inside the view. If its finger is still inside the view before user does a touch up i dont want to cancel the touch

Comment: @user866821 I believe there's a `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE` for that.